# Find $\int \sqrt{\frac{(1-\sin x)(2-\sin x)}{(1+\sin x)(2+\sin x)}}dx$

Tags: integration

> How to find $$\int \sqrt{\frac{(1-\sin x)(2-\sin x)}{(1+\sin x)(2+\sin
>  x)}}dx$$ ?

I could get rid of of $(1+\sin x)$ by multiplying numerator and denominator by $(1-\sin x)$.What about the $(2+\sin x)$ term?
Any other method possible?

Comment: Have you tried [tangent-half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)?

Comment: I see [elliptic integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) here. [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+Sqrt%5B(1-Sin%5Bx%5D)(2-Sin%5Bx%5D)%2F((1%2BSin%5Bx%5D)(2%2BSin%5Bx%5D))%5D) doesn't show any closed form though

Comment: I tried after you said.But I still can't simplify the term $(2-\sin x)/(2+\sin x) $which comes out as $(1-t+t^2)/(1+t+t^2)$.What to do?

Comment: @SanchayanDutta, as I said, look up elliptic integrals. Are you certain you need the indefinite integral?